# Trigger Event in Excel VBA when Row or Column is hidden

Tags: excel, vba, row, hide, ribbon

Is there a way, to trigger an event (call a sub) in Excel VBA, when i manually hide a row/column?

I want the same row to be hidden in all following sheets, when it is hidden in a particular sheet.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: EXCELLENT question - there is no direct way to do it (no Column_Hide type event afaik), but there is a workaround, which I'll post after testing. Are you using Excel 2007 or newer?

Comment: Hi, was the answer below useful?

Answer (score 8):

There is no direct event trigger to capture hiding or unhiding columns. There are clumsy workarounds, using formulae in cells but those feel like a kludge when using and not really flexible.

However, there is an indirect way to capture this event if you use Excel 2007 or newer. This is neat and extremely flexible.

1. **Modify the Ribbon XML (if it's present):** You need to be able to modify the Ribbon's `customUI14.xml` (for Excel 2010) or `customUI.xml` (for Excel 2007).
2. **Create the custom Ribbon UI XML file (if not present):** You may use Ron De Bruin's excellent Custom UI Editor from http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm (which is also endorsed in quite a few official Microsoft examples).
3. **XML changes for capturing events:** Open the Excel file in the Custom UI Editor and add the XML code as shown below. That will enable a column hide or unhide event to trigger a macro in your code.
4. **VBA code to execute your actions:** Add the code listed below to take action once the event is captured.

**Reference:** This excellent solution was provided by Andy Pope [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a5d44c36-1953-49b5-9f22-e80fa06a1175/is-there-any-way-to-trigger-an-event-when-a-column-is-hidden?forum=exceldev) (MSDN link).

**Custom XML code:**

```
<customUI  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" >
    <commands >
        <command 
            idMso="ColumnsHide"
            onAction="Column_Hide_Macro"/>
        <command 
            idMso="ColumnsUnhide"
            onAction="Column_UnHide_Macro"/>
    </commands >
</customUI>
```

**Custom UI Editor screenshot:**
[image]

**VBA code:**

```
Sub Column_Hide_Macro(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef CancelDefault)
    MsgBox ("You have hidden a column")

    ' You may put your code here
    ' to check if your monitored row is hidden

    CancelDefault = False   ' This enables the default action to continue
End Sub

Sub Column_UnHide_Macro(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef CancelDefault)
    MsgBox ("You have unhidden a column")

    ' You may put your code here
    ' to check if your monitored row is unhidden

    CancelDefault = False   ' This enables the default action to continue
End Sub
```

Comment: Great  thanks for your answer , It is working.