# Excel hiding columns

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a function in module VBA to count visible columns

EX.

```
Public Function HideCol(cells As Range) As Integer
i = 0

For Each col In cells.Columns
    If col.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next col

HideCol = i
End Function
```

When i set `formular =HideCol(A1:Z1)`, it works
but when i hide a column, it did not update, unless i change any value in that range.

Comment: That's how Excel manages cell formula recalculations - it doesn't re-run the calculation unless one of the inputs changes.  You can use `Application.Volatile` which will trigger your UDF to be recalculated whenever any other formula on the sheet is calculated, but that still won't respond to hiding a column.

Comment: There is no direct way to achieve what you want as there is no event which can trap the hiding and showing of columns. Having said that, is it possible to achieve what you want? YES! But the soultion is pretty complex as it uses APIs and Subclassing. If you google you may find a "ready" code which you can try but I would not recommend it if you have not worked with APIs before.

Comment: BTW you can use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777074/trigger-event-in-excel-vba-when-row-or-column-is-hidden) to call `Application.Calculate` instead of showing a message box to achieve what you want.  This will recalculate the formulas. I just tested it and it works as per your requirements.