# Automatically set optimal height of visible columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a fairly large Excel sheet, but I'm only interested in a certain amount of columns at a time. Now some columns contain quite a long text requiring a large cell height. After hiding these columns I wanted to set the cell heights of the visible rows rescaled to the optimum height for better browsing my sheet.

How can these be achieved in Excel either out-of-the-box or with a special rescale VBA Macro?

I'm not an Excel specialist, so any help is welcome her.

Comment: As far as i know, there is no out of the box way to do it. The solution i have in mind is a loop which goes through all lines, copies the value of cell, paste it in a test row and test the optimal height using autofit. If this is very big, it may requires a few seconds/minutes i think. How big is the spreadsheet?

Comment: @snenson use len() to find the cell with the most characters...

Comment: @SolarMike This is not how i understand the question. I think he wants to set the optimal height for e.g column E, it doesnt matter if there is more text in column G or F or whatever, it just need to fit for this one column. if i am wrong needs to be said by Aleph0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have set the cells having long text to "Wrap Text". If you reset this, text is shown in one row now matter how long the content is.

If you do this for all columns that are hidden, Excel is able to calculate the needed height properly:

```
Sub setheight()
    Dim col As Range
    For Each col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns
        ' Set WrapText to false if column is hidden
        col.WrapText = Not col.Hidden
    Next
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Unfortunately there is no easy way to trigger this automatically as there is no event that is fired when a column is shown/hidden (yes, there is one, but this is related to the ribbon. If you want to have a look, see [Trigger Event in Excel VBA when Row or Column is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777074/trigger-event-in-excel-vba-when-row-or-column-is-hidden))

There are numerous ways to trigger the sub, you could for example create a keyboard shortcut to the macro. An alternative that I use sometimes is to create a trigger on DoubleClick on a specific cell or range. I would suggest to run the code when the top row is Double-Clicked. Put the following code into the Worksheet-module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Row > 1 Then Exit Sub
    setheight
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```