# Prevent/disable Hide Rows without using Protect sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to Prevent/disable  Hide Rows without using Protect sheet ?
Because some users can hide some rows by mistake.I tried using this code on `SelectionChange` event but not full prove.
Thanks for your help.

```
Activewindow.displayHeadings = False
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no event triggered when a row is hidden.

The following code will not prevent that rows are hidden, but it will immediately show them again when the cursor is set to any other cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry , but I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777074/trigger-event-in-excel-vba-when-row-or-column-is-hidden

Comment: You don't need to be sorry. If you find a working solution, go ahead, you can even answer your own question (and accept it) on SO. However, I have the feeling that the linked solution is tricky to implement.

Comment: The implement is very easy, and the advantage is `it works per Workbook only` has this code