# Trigger a macro to run on specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Regarding this question [Trigger Event in Excel VBA when Row or Column is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777074/trigger-event-in-excel-vba-when-row-or-column-is-hidden).

The provided answer applies to the workbook, but I need it to run on specific sheets (same workbook).

I tried the following modification, but it runs on the whole workbook also.

```vb
Sub Row_Hide_Macro(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef CancelDefault)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name = "Sheet1" Or ws.name = "Sheet2" Then
            CancelDefault = True
        Else
            CancelDefault = False
       End If
   Next
End Sub
```

I also tried

```vb
Sub Row_Hide_Macro(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef CancelDefault)
    If Not Intersect(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")) Is Nothing Then
         CancelDefault = True
     Else
         CancelDefault = False
     End If
End Sub
```

Error raised on Intersect line

> Type mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're not checking a specific sheet name in this code.

In the `For` loop you are iterating through all worksheets and updating the value of `CancelDefault`.  I suspect that you want to only update `CancelDefault` based on the name of the sheet that you hid a row or column on.

Try this (untested):

```
Sub Row_Hide_Macro(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef CancelDefault)

    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Or ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2" Then
         CancelDefault = True
    Else
         CancelDefault = False
    End If
       
End Sub
```

Here you only check the name of the sheet that had a change made to it, and update the value of `CancelDefault` based on the name of that single worksheet.

Comment: It works , But it is advisable to use `Thisworkbook` instead of Activeworkbook

Comment: @user145212 Why that? Do you understand what does `Thisworkbook` mean? In which workbook did you change the Ribbon XML code? In the above way it works for the Active Workbook, **as it should**. The important issue in the above code is using of `ActiveSheet`! I am curious how will it behave if you programmatically hide columns in a not activated sheet... Just for the sake of theoretical approach. Otherwise, you already know about the action.

Comment: @FaneDuru ,sure I understand what `Thisworkbook mean` it means workbook has this code.infact the macro works without even writing Activeworkbook or thisworkbook.Ribbon xml found in same file

Comment: @user145212 Exactly!. Otherwise, it will work only for such an action in `ThisWorkbook`, which I think is not the need. Usually such ribbon modifications are done in add-ins, which do not expose any sheet...

Comment: @FaneDuru and the advantage of modified Ribbon XML that it apply locally for that workbook and not global on all opened Excel files 

Comment: @user145212 In most situations I recommend using `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`.  It keeps things safer.  In this case, I didn't know enough about your situation to confirm that `ThisWorkbook` would be better, but I did know that you wanted an event to fire just after the user did something to a sheet in a workbook.  Because the user just interacted with the sheet, we know that the `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` will refer to the correct sheet.

Comment: @user145212 Of course, if your intention is to make it working only on the workbook keeping the code, yes, this is the solution. But not **In most situations**. I used an adapted Ribbon extremely rarely otherwise than in an add-in. And in such a case, using `ThisWorkbook` will be useless. The answer as it was formulated, **without your mention that you need it acting on that specific workbook** is more appropriate. At least, on my taste...

Comment: @user145212 I remembered about this discussion and I like to emphasize the next situation, which may appear, if you **will use what you think is the best**: If `ThisWorkbook` have "Sheet1" as active and you work on any different workbook, the event will not let you hiding  **any row**. Because of the fact that `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"`! In order to obtain what you need you should also add another condition: `If ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook`, which should return `True`.

Comment: @FaneDuru , I tried by opened two workbooks with identical sheets names and design.
My macro runs perfectly only on the workbook (has code inside).
In fact , no need at all to use Activeworkbook or Thisworkbook , because the macro use `ActiveSheet.`

Comment: @user145212 But **exactly** this is what I am trying to emphasize! Using what you tried explaining is wrong and you can better understand why, trying the scenario I tried explaining above...